# Android's Wait function

Tags: android

I have a snippet of Android code, My understanding is a new thread is created in the background which starts the record function.    It waits for 10seconds
But my question how to stop the recording.   From the record function it stops when the boolean isRecording is false.

My question is isRecording turns false after 10 seconds?

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            isRecording=true;
        record();              //starts to record
        } 
        });
        thread.start();   //thread start


     //=============================================//

        synchronized (this) 
        {

     try {
     wait(10000);

                  //wait for 10second
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    isRecording = false;   

    try {
      thread.join();  //blocks the current thread until the receiver finish execution and dies.
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {}     //interruptedException

   }
  }


   public void record() {


        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize]; 
        audioRecord.startRecording();

        while (isRecording) {
            int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++)
            dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
            }

        audioRecord.stop();
        dos.close();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("AudioRecord","Recording Failed");
        }

}
```

Comment: When do you want to stop the recording?

Comment: p.s. Please fix the indentation in your code. Currently it is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, // 10 second countdown
9999) // onTick time, not used 
{

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         // Not used
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         isRecording = false;
     }
}.start();
```